# Push/Pull information from one exe application into another exe application using dll as bridge

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

I have one exe applicaiton which loads one custom dll , now i want the same dll also to be loaded by second exe applicaiton, so that i can push/pull information between the two exe applications.

First Application is a third party application.   DLL i have coded myself, and the second application is also coded by me.

HOW can i make the second applicaiton also load the same dll and talk to the first application ?

Comment: Search term for first part [C# inject DLL](http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+inject+DLL), for the second part (talk) - http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+ipc . Hopefully it will get you started and you'll be able to ask more concrete question.

Comment: Just loading the dll two times will not result in any communication. The loaded instances do not share state.